# Valid subset claim

Tags: linear-algebra

I have proved that $kerT^n \subseteq kerT^{n+1}$.
Now I'm trying to use it in another question, I want to show that if $kerT^n=\{0\}$ then $kerT=\{0\}$.

Is it valid to write it this way:
... We have shown that $kerT^n\subseteq kerT^{n+1}$ so $kerT\subseteq$ $kerT^2\subseteq$ $kerT^3\subseteq$ ... $\subseteq$ $kerT^n$
for all $n>=1$ and therefore if $kerT^n=\{0\}$ then $kerT=\{0\}$.

Can I claim it this way, or I have to prove it in another way? (Induction for instance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were I to write this in an assignment or test, I'd write
$$\{0\} \subseteq \ker T \subseteq \ker T^2 \subseteq \ldots \subseteq \ker T^n = \{0\} \implies \ker T = \{0\}.$$
That'd be as much detail as I'd write down. There is a very simple induction proof being suppressed here, namely that given $\ker T^i \subseteq \ker T^{i+1}$ implies $\ker T \subseteq \ker T^n$ (basically extended transitivity of the subset relation). However, this is likely not the point of the exercise. I would suggest not bothering writing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. But I think that a more natural approach is this: if $\ker T\ne\{0\}$, there is some $v\ne0$ such that $T(v)=0$. But then $T^n(v)=0$, and therefore $\ker T^n\ne\{0\}$.